# Arduino Variable in PROGMEM R"=====( HTML

Tags: html, string, arduino, arduino-c++

I want to add the `IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP()` to the `const char root[] PROGMEM = R"=====(HTML code here)=====";` that holds an HTML page on my Arduino.

But I can't seem to get it to display it on the webpage.

The IPAddress `ip = WiFi.localIP()` will be converted to a `String` by `ip.toString()`, and I want to insert this `String` into the HTML in the `const char root[]`.

The result should be: `"<h4>IP:"+ip.toString()+"</h4>"`

Can anyone help me find a way to add the Arduino's `LocalIP()` address to the HTML page which is stored in `PROGMEM`?

Comment: What kind of syntax is that?

Comment: PROGMEM is for Arduino @tadman

Comment: Sure, but that definition still needs to have valid syntax and I'm not sure what the ===( stuff is all about.

Comment: ```const char root[] PROGMEM = R"=====( //Put your HTML CODE HERE )=====";``` @tadman

Comment: That looks a lot better as now it has closing quotes, etc.

Comment: You're really not able to make function calls into global variables, so you may need a function that computes and returns that string instead of a `const` variable.

Comment: Without duplicating the whole site you may need to divide it up. Like `client.print(progmem_prefix);client.print(ip.toString());client.print(progmem_suffix);` to have the static parts is progmem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change your HTML page as stored in `char root[]` because it is `const`, and it has to be `const` to be able to be stored in `PROGMEM`.

You could split up your webpage into two parts: the first containing all the HTML before the IP address you want to show, and the second with the rest of the HTML after the IP address, then store both HTML fragments in `PROGMEM`. You can then first send the first part, then the IP address, and then the second part, to your client.

Another option is to add a bit of Javascript to your page that retrieves the IP address from the Arduino using XHR after the page has loaded, and then inserts the IP address into the page in the right place.

A third and simpler option: if you open the webpage in a browser using the Arduino's IP address in the address bar, you can insert the Arduino's IP address into the page by using something like this in your webpage:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h4 ID="IP"></h4>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("IP").innerHTML = location.hostname;
  </script>  
</html>
```

Note that this will insert the hostname; if the host is given by name instead of by IP address, it will insert the name.